# Getting an object from a class array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript class like,

```
class Snake{
    constructor(id, trail){
        this.velocityX = 0;
        this.velocityY = -1;
        this.trail = trail;
        this.id = id;
    }
    moveRight(){
        console.log('move');
    }
}
```

and an array that stores Snake objects.

```
this.snakeList = new Array();
this.snakeList.push(new Snake(10, newSnakeTrail));
this.snakeList.push(new Snake(20, newSnakeTrail));
this.snakeList.push(new Snake(30, newSnakeTrail));
this.snakeList.push(new Snake(22, newSnakeTrail));
this.snakeList.push(new Snake(40, newSnakeTrail));
```

For example, I want to remove the element from the array which id is 20.

How can I do that?

Comment: use filter to remove it?

Comment: You are asking 2 questions. First -  is how to find an Object in an Array by `key/value`. Second - How to remove an item from an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this

```
this.snakeList = this.snakeList.filter(x => x.id != 20);
```

```js
let snakes = [{name: 'fuss', id: 10}, {name: 'huss', id: 20}, {name: 'hurr', id: 60}]
//Before removal
console.log("Before removal");
console.log(snakes);

snakes = snakes.filter(x => x.id != 20);

//After removal
console.log("After removal");
console.log(snakes);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Now I have one more question. If I add any method to snake class like 'moveRight()', can I call the method for a specific snake.

Comment: For example, snakeList.filter(x => x.id == 22).moveRight();

Comment: `if(snakeList.filter(x => x.id == 22).length){ moveRight();}`

Comment: Okay sorry for my second question. Also, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var snakeList = [
{
id:10,
trail:{}
},
{
id:20,
trail:{}
},
{
id:30,
trail:{}
}
]

snakeList.forEach((x,index)=>{

if(x.id === 20){
snakeList.splice(index,1)
}
})

console.log(snakeList)
```

See this is the working example
hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I'd use splice here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < snakes.length; i++) {
    var obj = snakes[i];
    if (obj.id === 20) {
        snakes.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
let snakes = [{name: 'fuss', id: 10}, {name: 'huss', id: 20}, {name: 'hurr', id: 60}]

for (var i = 0; i < snakes.length; i++) {
    var obj = snakes[i];
    if (obj.id === 20) {
        snakes.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}

console.log(snakes)
```